# SQL find First In and Last Out time (with overlap and multiple row)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, time

I Have a table which contain the in & Out time, now i would like to retrieve the First in and Last Out time.

but i have no idea how to get the last out time across multiple rows

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GUDi.png)

## Source

```
ID            IN Time                 Out Time
===  =======================    =======================
 A   2019-05-12 23:06:00.000    2019-05-13 03:00:00.000
 B   2019-05-14 09:01:00.000    2019-05-14 11:05:00.000
 C   2019-05-14 09:13:00.000    2019-05-14 17:33:00.000
 D   2019-05-14 16:15:00.000    2019-05-14 16:30:00.000
 E   2019-05-14 21:45:00.000    2019-05-14 22:12:00.000
```

## Expected Result

```
    ID         First In                   Last Out
    ===   =======================   =======================
     A    2019-05-12 23:06:00.000   2019-05-13 03:00:00.000
   B,C,D  2019-05-14 09:01:00.000   2019-05-14 17:33:00.000
     E    2019-05-14 21:45:00.000   2019-05-14 22:12:00.000
```

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZmV3.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Can't open the link of pictures.

Comment: updated :( my bad

Comment: You're lacking serious details on your requirements here. How have you decided that A should be in a row by itself, B, C & D together and E in a 3rd grouping by itself?

Comment: Ben, since the time are overlapping,
B In -> C In -> B Out (but C Not Out ) -> D In -> D Out (C Not Out)-> C Out (All are out) ####

if the E In Time change to 2019-05-14 16:45, then expected result will be B,C,D,E together , First in Remain 09:01, Last out will be 22:12

Answer (score 0):

You should run the table like this:
1) set a parameter @outTime = the time out of rhis row.
2) check the next row: if the start time is before then check it's time in: If it is later - set @out time to it, and continue this check.
I write the idea of the query \ function:

```
@outTime = FirstRow.timeout
@inTime = FirstRow.timein
@id = ""
for(row in table)
{
    if(row.timein < @outTime)
    {
        if(row.timeout > @outTime)
        {
            @outTime = row.timeout
        }
        @id.concatenate("," + row.id)
        check next row
        after this loop:
        *print row(@id, @timein, @timeout)
    }
    check next row
}
```